# How to Display Specific Child Nodes in for loop

Tags: jquery, html, child-nodes

In my current html code, I have a table that contains in the following order:

Stock ID   |  Product  |   Regular Price   |    Sale Price

The issue I am facing is that when I click on the values in the rows and append them to another table, or shopping cart, my for loop appends the whole line.
What I am looking for is to append only the Product, Sale Price, and then my calculated "amount saved" price. How do I append the index eq(1) [Product] and eq(3) [Sale Price] instead? From what I understand I should use another .find method but not sure how to do this exactly. (still getting the whole .find and child nodes down)

Code snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/ko828bcs/

Ps: I have jquery not javascript so it doesn't run in jsfiddle(I just wanted you to be able to see the formatting)

my code that does all the work is:

```
//add the selected item in table
var variable = "<tr class='s-list' id='s-"+id +"'>";
for (var i=0; i<child_nodes.length; i++){
        // add a table cell for each node using its content
        variable += "<td>" +child_nodes.eq(i).text() + "</td>";
} // end for
    variable += "</tr>";
    // add msg to the selected courses list
    $('#selected-list').append(variable);
```

However as you can see I use eq(i) which gives the whole line.

File:

```
<script>

//makes gray in table
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".list:odd").css('background-color', '#eee');
});

$(function() {

    $('#selected-list').on('click', 's-list',function(){

        alert($(this).children().eq(0).text());
        //delete this element
        $(this).remove();
    });

    $('.list').on('click', function(){

        //rest background color
        $('.list').css('background-color', '#fff');

        //change background color
        $(this).css('background-color', '#eee');        

        //read its id attribute
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        //alert(id);

        //Check if it has already been added
        if ($('#selected-list').find('#s-'+id).length > 0){

            alert("The product is already selected. Please choose a different one!");
        }
        else {

        // find  child nodes
        var child_nodes = $(this).children();
        // read current total
        var current_total = parseInt($('#total').val());
        //read selected sale price
        var selected_sale= parseInt(child_nodes.eq(3).text());
        //read initial price
        var selected_price = parseInt(child_nodes.eq(2).text());            
        //saving amount for each selected
        var savings = selected_price - selected_sale;


        //add the selected item in table and update total
        var variable = "<tr class='s-list' id='s-"+id +"'>";
        for (var i=0; i<child_nodes.length; i++){
            // add a table cell for each node using its content
            variable += "<td>" +child_nodes.eq(i).text() + "</td>";
        } // end for
        variable += "</tr>";
        // add msg to the selected courses list
        $('#selected-list').append(variable);


        //update total cost
        // read the current total
        var total = parseInt($('#total').val());
        // add the selected item cost to the total
        total += parseInt(child_nodes.eq(3).text());

        // update the total cost
        $('#total').val(total); 

        // Reset background color of all the rows
        $('.courselist').css('background-color', '#fff');

        // Change background color of the selected row
        $(this).css('background-color', '#eee');
        }


    });
});


</script>

</head>
<body>
<h2>Sam's Store</h2>
<div class="content">
<div class='title'>Deals of the  Week</div>
<div class='labels'>
<div class='cell1' id='sid1'>Stock ID</div>
<div class='cell2' id='pid1'>Product</div>
<div class='cell3' id='rpid1'>Regular Price</div>
<div class='cell4' id='spid1'>Sale Price</div>
</div>

<div class='list' id='c1'>
<div class='cell1' id='sid2'>SH32AQ60</div>
<div class='cell2' id='pid2'>Sharp AQUAS-60in  HDTV</div>
<div class='cell3' id='rpid2'>799.99</div>
<div class='cell4' id='spid2'>759.99</div>
</div>
<div class='list' id='c28'>
<div class='cell1' id='sid3'>PN455</div>
<div class='cell2' id='pid13'>Panasonic 55in LED HDTV</div>
<div class='cell3' id='rpid3'>999.99</div>
<div class='cell4' id='spid3'>679.99</div>
</div>
<div class='list' id='c60'>
<div class='cell1' id='sid4'>VZ49M</div>
<div class='cell2' id='pid4'>VIZIO M series 49in LED HDTV</div>
<div class='cell3' id='rpid4'>719.99</div>
<div class='cell4' id='spid4'>579.99</div>
</div>
<div class='list' id='c62'>
<div class='cell1' id='sid5'>IN200SR</div>
<div class='cell2' id='pid5'>Insignia 200W Stereo Receiver</div>
<div class='cell3' id='rpid5'>24.99</div>
<div class='cell4' id='spid5'>19.99</div>
</div>

<div class='list' id='c6'>
<div class='cell1' id='sid6'>PN1000HTS</div>
<div class='cell2' id='pid6'>Panasonic 1000W Smart Blu-ray Home Theater System</div>
<div class='cell3' id='rpid6'>349.99</div>
<div class='cell4' id='spid6'>299.99</div>
</div>
<div class='list' id='c7'>
<div class='cell1' id='sid7'>HP305DJ</div>
<div class='cell2' id='pid7'>HP Deskjet 3056A</div>
<div class='cell3' id='rpid7'>49.90</div>
<div class='cell4' id='spid7'>34.90</div>
</div>
<div class='list' id='c8'>
  <div class='cell1' id='sid8'>RF386BMR</div>
  <div class='cell2' id='pid8'>Rocketfish Bluetooth Music Receiver</div>
  <div class='cell3' id='rpid8'>49.90</div>
  <div class='cell4' id='spid8'>34.90</div>
</div>
<div class='list' id='c9'>
    <div class='cell1' id='sid9'>SM350SB</div>
    <div class='cell2' id='pid9'>Sling Media Slingbox 350</div>
    <div class='cell3' id='rpid9'>179.90</div>
    <div class='cell4' id='spid9'>115.90</div>
</div>


</div>

<div id="shop">
 <div class="shoppinglist">
<div class='list-title'>You have <span id="items">0</span>  items in your Shopping Cart</div>
  <div >

  <div class='cell2'>Product</div>
  <div class='cell3'>Sale Price</div>
  <div class='cell4'>You Save</div>

  <div class='table selected-list' id='selected-list'></div>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<div class="total">Total Amount: $<span id="total"></span></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could just use an if conditional inside your loop

```
 for (var i=0; i<child_nodes.length; i++){
        if(i == 1 || i == 3)
        {
            variable += "<td>" +child_nodes.eq(i).text() + "</td>";
        }
    } // end for
    variable += "</tr>";
```

Or maybe just add the two nodes you want

```
    var variable = "<tr class='s-list' id='s-"+id +"'>";
    variable += "<td>" +child_nodes.eq(1).text() + "</td>";
    variable += "<td>" +child_nodes.eq(3).text() + "</td>";
    variable += "</tr>";
```

Comment: Oh wow. Sadly, I seriously thought it was suppose to be way more complicated then what you showed O.o . The top one works just fine. If you don't mind me asking, I have a variable value 

`var savings = selected_price - selected_sale.`

For savings I want after the sale price. Why can't I just do:

 `variable += "<td>" +child_nodes.eq(i).text() + savings.eq(i).text() "</td>";` ?

Comment: That has a couple issues, first `savings` is an int, so the `.eq(1)`  which is a jquery function to be called on a query object like `child_nodes`.  You will probably get a property not defined, or null error.  Also if you add this inside your for loop you will be adding the savings value to every child node that you are copying.  So what you are looking for might be `variable += "<td>" + savings + "</td>";` after the loop but before adding the closing `</tr>` to `variable`

Comment: Ya I saw that savings works for your second option and not your first. Thanks!